# iOS: strings.xml equivalent in iOS app dev?

Tags: ios

In the app I'm making I have a lot of huge strings. I don't want to hardcode these into my code because it makes the code unbearably messy. When I made a similar android app, it was a simple matter of declaring the string in strings.xml as

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello World!!</string>
```

and accessing it in the java file with

```
getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

How can I do something like this with iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put them into a `.plist` file and load them using the following code (which assumes a file called `strings.plist` which has been copied into the app bundle):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"strings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *string1 = [dict objectForKey:@"string1"];
```

However if you want to internationalize your app, then using [Apple's Internationalization and Localization](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) technology might be something to look at instead.

**EDIT**: you'll want to load that file/dictionary only once and keep it around the entire app lifetime; don't use the above code for every string access!

Comment: app bundle means the same folder where all my .h and .m files are?

Comment: @Kartik_Koro Yes.  you will need to add the file to in the Xcode `Build Phases` settings so it's copied into the app bundle during a build (although I think Xcode will do that automatically for you if you use the `File -> Add File` interface).