# Changing the text in an iOS or Android app that I didn't make?

Tags: android, ios

There is a game in the community I am in which has a Chinese version, which is incredibly different from the international version.

I know Chinese, and would like to make a "patch" if you will to make the game English by rewriting the text in it.

Is there any way to do this for iOS and/or Android? Note that if you only know how to do one, please tell me; one out of two isn't bad.

Comment: do you have access to the source code of the app?

Comment: no, and i know for a fact that i will not be able to get it

Answer (score 1):

### Android

You'll need to decompile the APK, replace the `strings.xml` and recompile the APK. (You can't edit the APK directly, because strings are merged into resources.arsc)

Alternatively you can look into Xposed, it provides methods to replace resources at runtime, but requires a rooted device.

Comment: Can you tell me more about Xposed and how it would help in translation?

Comment: Also there are already  modules which help with translations http://repo.xposed.info/module/dv.dv_translate http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.misopes.resoverloader

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer for Android and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238613/ios-strings-xml-equivalent-in-ios-app-dev) can help with iOS.

I have to make a few assumptions though.

- #1. You have access to the source code and can modify it
- #2. The
  developers of the app put texts into strings.xml instead of
  hardcoding

**If both of the above assumptions are true you can:**

create a new strings.xml file with translations and put it in values-cn/strings.xml. Android will automatically pick up the correct strings.xml based on the device language.

**If only #1 is true:**

you have to move all hardcoded texts into values/strings.xml first, then create a translation strings.xml.

**If #1 is not true:**

I wouldn't recommend you making further efforts translating the app. Ask for source code access from the makers of the app

Comment: I don't have access to the source code, nor will the owners give it to me (I can guarantee that)